# Configure Google Voice SMS with Digsby IM

Tags: chat, sms, google-voice

I want to be able to view my google voice sms messages as an IM service in Digsby. I can easily create an email, and set up email filters and forwarding, but that is not the solution I am looking for. Is there a plugin or hack that will enable me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.daveamenta.com/2009-10/howto-google-voice-sms-in-digsby-with-digsbygv-1-1/